# Arrow keys not moving pygame.surface diagonally when two keys are pressed

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I am using python 3, on Pycharm CE, on a MacBook Air. I have previously and am currently working on basic games that use pygame. For some reason, when I am holding the down key to go down, then press the right key, it moves the player diagonally down to the right (which is what I like). However, when I move right, and then simultaneously press the up key, it does not do this behavior. It is not limited to just right/down keys, its just if I am moving the player down/up and simultaneously press left/right, then it moves diagonally. However if I am moving the player right/left and simultaneously press up/down, then it doesn't move diagonally.

I think it has something to do with the way pycharm, pygame, or python processes keyboard input, but I am not certain. Anyone else having these issues/annoyances?

```
    def key_pressed(self):

        key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.vx = 500

        elif key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.vx = -500

        elif key_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.vy = -500

        elif key_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.vy = 500

        else:
            self.vy = 0
            self.vx = 0



    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.vx * self.game.dt
        self.rect.y += self.vy * self.game.dt


        self.key_pressed()
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @Coder22 okay I added the basic function for what I am using

Comment: Did you get it working Addison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer posted above almost gets you there- the problem I think is that you only reset the vx and vy values if no keys are pressed.  It seems less than ideal but having two separate blocks may solve the problem.  In the above posted code the "else" only gets activated if the last "if" is true.

```
def key_pressed(self):

    key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] or key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.vx = 500
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.vx = -500
    else:
        self.vx = 0

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_UP] or key_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.vy = 500
        if key_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.vy = -500
    else:
        self.vy = 0
```

Try this out and let us know if it fixes the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the elif statements with if statements, so then it won't skip over any of the key presses:

```
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.vx = 500

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.vx = -500

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.vy = -500

    if key_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.vy = 500

    else:
        self.vy = 0
        self.vx = 0
```

Comment: hmm, now it behaves very inconsistently. Left and right sometimes work, but up and down don't seem to. If I press down then left/right, it sort of works, but it seems to stutter. Any thoughts?